# closeup filter vs dedicated macro lens

Tags: macro, filters, field-of-view, macro-converter

I want to click macro pictures, so was wondering closeup filter for my 18-55mm and 50-200mm as a cheap macro solution. Lately I've been doing more macro work, so I've been thinking about cheap solutions. I mostly take macro shots of insects.

I know DOF is slim at the best of times in macro work, but my question is this: Would there be any difference in DOF when using a closeup filter vs a dedicated macro lens? Or better is closeup filter a best option for cheap macro setup?

Any suggestion will be appreciated.